# How to extract rar and show the program?

Tags: c#, security

I have a rar archive, I shake it to the ftp folder to be stored in the folder files.
How do I unzip the archive, that archive would not be seen in the system?

that would not have been possible to users of its intercept.

archive - the secret information, I can not open whatever it could to keep

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused: you're trying to extract a RAR archive, but prevent *what users* to see the files? Are you trying to crack it, or are you trying to prevent other users from cracking it?

Answer (score 0):

Load into memory file content and decrypt in memory then you can traverse content without saving this secret data on hard disk or other `I/O` device.

Comment: more please. I have it and do not understand how to do it